# Confusion regarding the selection rule in hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, hydrogen

The selection rules I'm aware of are:

$$\Delta l = \pm 1$$

$$\Delta m = \pm 1 \text{ or } 0$$

However, I noticed that the state $3d_{5/2}$ cannot transition $2p_{1/2}$ even though $\Delta l = -1$. This made me think there is another selection rule for $j$ which is $\Delta j = \pm 1$.

But if that was the case, then the transition from $3p_{1/2}$ to $2s_{1/2}$ should not be allowed because $\Delta j = 0$, which is not the case. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

When you describe your state as $3 D_{5/2}$ you are assuming so-called LS coupling. In that case, the actual selection rule for $J$ (a quantum number resulting from the coupling between electron's spin $S$ and its angular momentum $L$) is $\Delta J = \pm 1, 0 $, except transitions from $J=0$ to $J'=0$, which are forbidden.